# Redirect to New Page after Post Action

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, form-submit

currently when my form is submitted 'Application Successful' text appears on the same page. How do i get form to submit to a thank you page?

This is my code:

```
    <div role="form" class="col-lg-8" id="wpcf7-f4-p7902-o1" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
        <form action="<?php echo $apply_permalink; ?>" method="post">
            <?php if($post_saved){ ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success">Application Successful.</div>
            <?php }?>
            <p>
                <label> Your Name &amp; Surname (required)<br>
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
                        <input name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="text">
                    </span> 
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label> Your Email (required)<br>
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
                        <input name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="email">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label> Your Cell Number<br>
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">
                        <input name="your-cell" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-number" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="text">
                    </span>
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input value="Apply" class="wpcf7-form-control" type="submit">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I've tried to look at other submission with the same problem but the code is different from mine so the solutions don't apply to mine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I made the changes you suggested and the form correctly redirects to a new page.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/user.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();
```

**It is a good practice to call exit() right afterwords so that code below it does not get executed.**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitForm'])){
         header('location: https://google.com/');
         exit();
}
?>
```

It's important that you put this at the very top of the page, otherwise you can use JS

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitForm'])){
             echo "<script>window.location.href='https://google.com';</script>";
    }
    ?>
```